Azure DevOps Project Teams List Always Blank when Loading Page
We're using an onsite install of Azure DevOps 2022 and we seem to be having issues with it.  We're looking inside the Teams tab of our projects and the list is always blank the first time.  If we refresh the list at the top, it finally shows us the Team.  But we have to refresh it each time, from different peoples browsers and computers.  Somewhere, we tracked a potential issue where we caught a JavaScript error message:
ContributionData unavailable for 'ms.vss-admin-web.admin-project-home-data-provider'

We don't know if this is the actual error for this or if it's something else, because it led us down a rabbit hole to figure out.  Is this a known issue?  Or is it something weird that we have to set that we didn't know about?
